# Alexa Email Permission in Development Mode

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I wrote a skill that requires permission to the user email. The problem is I can't share the permission in the development mode and give access to the app. Also, I can't share the app with test users because they will also face the same problem.

My question is how to exactly give email permission when the app is in development mode?

Thanks,
H